# My dynamically allocated 2D array won't print

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to use a function to create a 2d character array, set all characters to character x, and print the first 10 rows to test if it was done correctly.

My code compiles using: gcc -std=c89 -pedantic code.c
However, when I try to run the code using ./a.out, I get a segmentation fault.

I have isolated the problem to when I try to print my array, as there is no segmentation fault when the line `printf("%c", a[i][j]);` is commented out.

```
#define rows 100
#define columns 3

char** makeArr(int rows, int columns)
{
    int temp,i,j;
    char** a = (char**)malloc(rows*sizeof(char*));
    for(temp = 0; temp < rows; temp++)
    {
        a[temp]=(char*)malloc(columns*sizeof(char));
    }

    memset(a, 'x', rows*columns*sizeof(a[0][0]));

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            printf("%c", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return a;
}
```

Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated, and if any more context is needed, just let me know.

Comment: `memset` fills the continuous region of memory. Since you allocate each 1D-array separately, they are not guaranteed to form the continuous region. You have to memset all 1D-arrays separately.

Comment: Your array is not a 2D array but a 1D array of pointers to 1D arrays. This is not the same.

Comment: [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: I tried removing the casts from malloc as suggested by Barmar but I am still getting a segmentation fault

Comment: This is relevant:  [**Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to do the `memset` in the same loop you `malloc` the rows in:

```
for(temp = 0; temp < rows; temp++) {
    a[temp] = malloc(columns*sizeof(char));
    memset(a[temp], 'x', columns);
}
```

Notice that I do not multiply `columns * sizeof(a[0][0])`. `sizeof(a[0][0])` is the size of a `char` in bytes, so usually 1. If you were to do `columns * sizeof(a[0][0])` it would still work on most any system, but in practical use, you really do not need it since `sizeof(char)` is almost universally 1.

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed the segmentation fault!

Comment: Correct answer, but I should point out that `sizeof(char)` is always 1 so you don't need to write it.

Comment: `columns * sizeof(a[0][0])` has the advantage of being correct, even when code later changes the `type` from `char` to say `wchar_t`.

Comment: `sizeof (char)` is *always* by definition 1, period, because the very definition of `sizeof` is that it gives the size of the given object in *chars*. A char might have more than 8 bits though.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso I do understand that, I keep it there so that it clearly indicates what type I'm allocating for. If I `malloc` right when I declare a variable, I might leave it off

Answer (score 2):

You can allocate the array as a contiguous block:

```
char (*arr)[COLUMNS] = malloc(sizeof *arr * ROWS);
memset(arr, 'x', sizeof *arr * ROWS);
```

The `memset` call is going beyond the bounds of the allocated array `a`:

```
memset(a, 'x', rows*columns*sizeof(a[0][0]));
```

The array is comprised of `char*` pointers and has `rows` elements. Since you're allocating the sub-arrays individually you'd need separate `memset` calls for each `malloc`'d pointer. Assuming the strings have a fixed length, it would be simpler to allocate the storage as one continuous block.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the problem, but how would I implement your solution?

Comment: You can allocate the array with `char (*arr)[COLUMNS] = malloc(sizeof *arr * ROWS)`